# Containers with same class to have separate jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hide, show

Okay so I made a quick program that shows the hidden text when you click on a box. The problem is, when you click on either box, it shows the text in both of them. I only want it to show the text from the box you clicked in.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.insidebox').hide ();

    $('.box').on('click', function(){

        $('.insidebox').fadeToggle();        

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specifically access the current *element*, for instance, via `this`.

```
$( this ).find( '.insidebox' ).fadeToggle();
```

Without that, jQuery will just query for any `.insidebox` element within the entire DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".box").on("click", function(){

    $(this).children(".insidebox").fadeToggle();        

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the implicit object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').on('click', function(){

        $(this).fadeToggle();        

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.insidebox').hide ();

   $('.box').on('click', function(){

      $(this).fadeToggle();        

  });

});
```